# CakePHP creating radio buttons

Tags: cakephp

How can I create two radio buttons with one being preselected based on the value of $foo? The snippet below creates them fine but does not select either of the two buttons.

```
$options = array('standard' => ' Standard','pro' => ' Pro');
$attributes = array(
    'legend' => false,
    'value' => false,
    'checked'=> ($foo == "pro") ? FALSE : TRUE,
);
echo $this->Form->radio('type',$options, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's simple.. use the default value to $foo:

```
$options = array(
    'standard' => 'Standard',
    'pro' => 'Pro'
);

$attributes = array(
    'legend' => false,
    'value' => $foo
);

echo $this->Form->radio('type', $options, $attributes);
```

As you can see on the documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::radio

Comment: a) he is using 1.3 - b) this answer is destroying the idea of "persistent forms". try it out yourself. post this form and see for yourself. if anything, you can use the form param "default" instead of "value".

Comment: value = always the same value - default = once it is posted and invalidates the form keeps the previously selected value (despite a different default value). thats why only default should be used.

Comment: And a bout boolean radio? where input database value is type boolean but cake (or PDO) shows 'f' and 't'?  I can't get  te boolean value to set the correct radio option (on edit.cpt).

Answer (score 3):

you should preselect the value for any form field from the controller

@see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ "Default Values"

Comment: well, its all laid out for you there in writing: in the ELSE block in your action set: $this->data[Model][field] = defaultvalue (in your case either 'standard' or 'pro'). and please mention your cakephp version in your next question! because for 2.0 it would be $this->request->data - but without knowing the version you are using it is hard to provide you with an exact solution.

Comment: So I can only preselect a radio button by putting code in the controller, while the actual markup to generate the radio is in the view? I'm using 1.3

Comment: you can always use the view (with some risks - key word "validation errors" and "persistent forms"). What I am saying (please also read the article more carefully) is that you shoudnt do that. thats where the controller is for after all - also see the comment to the other answer for details.

Comment: in 2.0 it seems to be at least possible to use "default" ("value" will break your form for sure). i just tried that. but i am still no fan of it.

Comment: Mark, TiuTalk's answer works for me but I understand it's not ideal. I could not get your solution to work, I think cause I'm processing the form in a different function from the one that generates it, so I don't have this else {} block that's mentioned in your article.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to go

```
    $attributes = array();
    $options = array('standard' => 'Standard', 'pro' => 'Pro');

    if($foo === 'pro') {
       $attributes['default'] = 'pro';
    }

    echo $this->Form->radio('type', $options, $attributes);
```

A better Solution is to set the defaults in the controller as Mark has pointed. That way you can set defaults at the end of your controller's action like...

Let's assume your Model is `Member` with `membership_type field`

```
   $this->data['Member']['membership_type '] = 'pro';
```

Comment: i disagree. default values for fields that can have more than one state are part of the logic and should be provided from the controller (your solution seems like overhead and will probably also break on validation failure). the only use case where it the view level is appropriate: if the default/value is fixated to a specific value (always stays the same).

Comment: yeah obviously the better way to do this is in controller. but this is just a possible solution as OP didn't ask which method method to use. I have updated the post, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

For CakePHP 3.x, the following syntax should work.

```
$options = array('Y'=>'Yes','N'=>'No');

$attributes = array('div' => 'input', 'type' => 'radio', 'options' => $options, 'default' => 'Y');

echo $this->Form->input('add to business directory',$attributes);
```

HTH

Comment: Just a heads up, In CakePHP 2.x I am not sure it is the case that this syntax will still work. Just a heads up of anyone that comes to this question.